# Translate HTML file in other languages

Tags: html, internationalization, translate

I have a landing page with HTML, CSS and JS (jQuery). How can I translate it on other languages? Can I do it with a JSON file? I haven't a package manager.

At this moment I have the HTML file duplicated, but it isn't a clean solution and Google will penalize me.

Comment: It seems hard to imagine Google will penalize you for pages in different languages?

Comment: Duplicate content I think. Either way better to have a single file...

Comment: I've never heard of a bunch of files in different languages being duplicate content. By serving stuff in a single file using JS, you'll make it less likely that your content can be properly indexed. Nothing wrong with a static multi-language structure like (for example) `domain.com/en/` `domain.com/es/` (or, more fancy, `domain.com`, `domain.es`)

Comment: I'm using "domain.com/en/" for languages at this moment, but I would rather to have one HTML file because now I must to edit 4 different files when I have some change to do. In the future I will have even more languages...

Comment: I understand, but as said, that'll seriously impede indexing. That's a huge downside and I don't think there is a cure. If you don't want everything in separate HTML files, you could always consider using a templating system of some kind

Comment: What do you recommend me? Is Handlebars a good option? I'm working with Angular in other project, but I think Angular is too much to translate a site.

Comment: I don't know enough about this all newfangled JS templating stuff (and its relationship with search engine indexing) to make a good recommendation I'm afraid! A server side templating system might be an option, too, depending on what platform(s) you are using.